# Multi Combobox Change Declaration

Tags: vba, excel

is there a simple command for loop combobox_change like the code below?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    nkm = cmbslno.ListIndex + 1
    Set wk = Sheets("kkm" & nkm)
    TextBox1.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox1, wk.Range("A33:B52"), 2, 0)
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    nkm = cmbslno.ListIndex + 1
    Set wk = Sheets("kkm" & nkm)
    TextBox2.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox2, wk.Range("A33:B52"), 2, 0)
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    nkm = cmbslno.ListIndex + 1
    Set wk = Sheets("kkm" & nkm)
    TextBox3.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox3, wk.Range("A33:B52"), 2, 0)
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox4_Change()
    nkm = cmbslno.ListIndex + 1
    Set wk = Sheets("kkm" & nkm)
    TextBox4.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox4, wk.Range("A33:B52"), 2, 0)
End Sub
```

I want to simplify in one command line

```
for i = 1 to 15
......... "code above" .....
next
```

Comment: What does 1 to 15 have to do with it? Is 15 the number of comboboxes?

Comment: yes. and also textbox

Comment: Are these part of a form?

Comment: yes. its part a form

Comment: I'm not sure about change events, i don't really have time to have a play but you might be able to do something via [controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932425/loop-through-comboboxes-vba)

Comment: what is this meant can not change combobox_change command as a whole?

Comment: the above command can be run, but on combobox4, error message appears .. why is that?

Comment: What is the error message? And what code are you running that generates it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve can be done using a procedure and be called 15 times.

```
Sub MyChange ()
  For i = 1 to 15
    Call ChangeCmb(i)
  Next
End Sub
```

Sub to be called:

```
Private Sub ChangeCmb(index as Integer)
    nkm = cmbslno.ListIndex + 1
    Set wk = Sheets("kkm" & nkm)
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.Controls("ComboBox" & i), wk.Range("A33:B52"), 2, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: where is combobox?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Learn to loop through controls. Here is a sample of your basic way to interact with your controls in a loop.

```
    Dim cCont As Control
    For Each cCont In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(cCont) = "CheckBox" Then
            Me.Controls("TextBox" & i) =  False
        End If
    Next cCont
    For Each cCont In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(cCont) = "TextBox" Then
            Me.Controls("TextBox" & i) = "whatever"
        End If
    Next cCont
    For Each cCont In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(cCont) = "ComboBox" Then
            Me.Controls("ComboBox" & i) = "whatever"
        End If
    Next cCont
```

You can do quite a bit with this *if* your controls have some kind of consistent naming convention. Your example it looks as if they do, but its worth mentioning b/c a lot of people don't put that much thought into their controls when first starting out.

Also beware that if you have tab strips that this will hit controls on those as well.

Comment: is not this the same as repeating code writing in the following line? I want to control a lot of combobox in one command.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign code (events) to controls in a loop.

The how to is, by using a class, wich you might find already hundreds of examples easily by searching.

If only certain of your combobox must do some action, in the loop you can test from the control's name or tag for example.

The good thing with class is that you write your events only once, and after you can assign it to nearly a limitless number of controls.

An other way of limiting the affected controls is by putting them into a container : frame, multitab, etc...

Comment: Can you write example