# Loop over ActiveX Objects in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, object, combobox

I am new to VBA in Excel and have some difficulties in understanding the principles of using loops for objects of ActiveX in Modules and User Forms.
I have several drop-down lists which was created using ActiveX ComboBox on the spreadsheet called Summary. After working with those lists, I would like to reset all of them to the initial position and delete content from some other cells using a button on the same page. Thus, I would be able to use this file as a universal template.
Here is a short example which seems to work:

```
Private Sub Clear_Click()
Worksheets("Summary").ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
Worksheets("Summary").ComboBox2.ListIndex = 0
Worksheets("Summary").ComboBox3.ListIndex = 0
Worksheets("Summary").Range("B4,B6:B8,B10:B12,B18:B21").Select
Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

But, because all boxes follow the pattern and I have many boxes, I was trying to implement the following loop using OLEObjects or Controls ([Loop through Comboboxes VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932425/loop-through-comboboxes-vba)). In both cases I experience the error either 1004 or 438 (object doesn't support property or method) respectively.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim cmb As ComboBox, i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 3
 Sheets("Summary").Controls ("ComboBox" & i).ListIndex = 0
‘ Sheets("Summary").OLEObjects("ComboBox" & i).ListIndex = 0
    Next i

End Sub
```

Could you please direct me towards a solution using loops or recommend the best practice for generating drop-down lists for templates with an option for resetting?

Comment: Perhaps you could loop through the collection of all OLEObjects and disregard the name?

Comment: The first time through the loop, you are looking for ComboBox0.  Is this valid?

Comment: @BrianMStafford You are right, should start from 1 instead of 0. Nevertheless, the correction did not change the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you just need to reference the `Object` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oleobjects)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim cmb As ComboBox, i As Integer, c As OLEObject

For i = 1 To 3
    Sheets("Summary").OLEObjects("ComboBox" & i).Object.ListIndex = 0
Next i

'alternative
'For Each c In Sheets("Summary").OLEObjects
'    c.Object.ListIndex = 0
'Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much @SJR ! Indeed, adding Object property solves the problem. Nevertheless, do you know why Controls solution might end up with an error? Am I not allowed to use Access objects for Excel?

Comment: Unlikely. You can use `Controls` when referring to a userform.